# how to access map of vectors?

Tags: c++, stl, mfc, dictionary, vector

I have created a map of vectors and populated it as follows. Here is the code. I am not able to post original code. It contains vectors of doubles

```
map <int, vector <double> > Maptest;

for (int i = 0 ; i < ID1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < ID2; j++)
    {
        Maptest[i].push_back(j*0.01);
    }
}

map <int, vector <double> >::iterator MaptestITR;
CString testString;
for ( j = 0 ; j < ID2; j++)
{
    for (i = 0 ; i < ID1; i++)
    {
        MaptestITR = Maptest.find(i);
        if (MaptestITR != Maptest.end())
        {
            testString.Format(_T("%f",MaptestITR->second.at(j)));
        }
        myfile << testString<< ',' ;
    }
}
```

But all values are updated as '0' (testString is '0'). In the IDE, the values are correctly shown in Watch.

What I am missing here?

Comment: May want to fix your formatting.

Comment: Maybe you can post a small, compilable example that shows the problem.

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand your problem, since the code is incomplete and we can't compile it. Please post more code so we have some context that we can use to help you.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure but I've never seen a class called "CString" in STL, though I may be remembering it wrongly. Is this from the MFC libraries? If so, could you please tag this accordingly?

Comment: I am really sorry since I didnt see the code. I have corrected the code sample. Please refer. and btw the IDE shows the value for MaptestITR as intended in Watch but I am not able to access it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector::at()` expects an integer parameter.  Specifically, a `size_t`.

I don't know what type `ID2` is, but from the code you gave it doesn't appear to be a `size_t`.

Comment: I am accessing the vector by its index as integer. Please answer the edited question.

Comment: filling the vector is same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293466/c-push-back-inside-a-map-of-vectors

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I booted up the Virtual Machine at work and ran an approximation of what your code might be. You've got some things in your code that I really don't understand.

Firstly, isn't your call to "at" accessing something outside the `vector`? Isn't it zero-referenced? In this case, maybe you're accessing something outside the `vector` each time, and as a result the behaviour isn't defined? Maybe try using `0` instead of `ID2` in

```
testString.Format(_T("%f",MaptestITR->second.at(ID2)));
```

Secondly, I ran this approximation, and got the result I expected. That is, I don't see why your code won't work, apart from the possible undefined behaviour I mentioned earlier.

Lastly, could you please explain what your code is trying to do? It appears to just access the same position in the only vector inside a map, after pushing back however many of the same number.

If anyone can give me a tip on how to copy from a VM I can also post the code approximation I was compiling on Linux.

...and now, back to work...

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that your program isn't creating the `map` that you think it is, and that your program isn't displaying the vector items that you think it is.

For the purposes of this answer, I'm assuming that the identifiers `ID1` and `ID2` are simple integer variables or macros that are simple integer constants (and have a value greater than 0, or the program will essentially do nothing). If `ID1` or `ID2` are something more complex, it's difficult to reason what the program should or might be doing without more information about what those identifiers are.

Lets look closely at what's happening in each nested loop.

In the first:

```
Maptest[ID1].push_back(ID2*0.01);
```

The `map` key being used is always the same since `ID1` isn't being changed. So `Maptest` only ever contains a single item, with a key value of `ID1` and a vector that gets elements added to it with each loop iteration. Also, each element that is added to the vector has the same value: `(ID2 * 0.01)`.

In particular, note that even though the nested loops are controlled by the variables `i` and `j`, those variables don't get used in the `push_back()` call.  So after that first nested loop completes, `Maptest` contains a single mapping, which has a key of `ID1` and a vector with `(ID1 * ID2)` elements in it.  Each element of that vector has a value of `(ID2 * 0.01)`.

In the second nested loop, you're always finding the same item in `Maptest` - the one with the key `ID1` (which happens to be the only item in the `map`). The `vector<double>` part of that mapping has an array with `(ID1 * ID2)` elements, each of which has the same value. The loop them formats the element at index `ID2` into `testString`.  Always the same element from the same vector.  Not that it really matters which element is formatted into the string, since each vector element has the same value.